# Ionic 4 error showing on using component in 2 pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have created a loader component and i am trying to use in my pages. Problem is its working fine in one page but when i am using in other page its showing error of

`component is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in`

This is my first page category.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';    
import { LoaderComponent } from '../loader/loader.component';    //this is component i am using    
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CategoryPageRoutingModule } from './category-routing.module';

import { CategoryPage } from './category.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    CategoryPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [CategoryPage, LoaderComponent]
})
export class CategoryPageModule {}
```

My other mage login.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';    
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';    
import { LoaderComponent } from '../loader/loader.component'; //this is component


import { LoginPageRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    LoginPageRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage, LoaderComponent]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

Now if i am removing my component from second page its working fine. And in app.module.ts i have added my component in declaration array.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are very well. You should think about creating a shared module, with this shared module you would have all your components/directives/pipes which you use around all the application.

Check this link

https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion provided by @bjdose. Below is an example of how you could implement the shared component.

You will want to have a `loader.module.ts` file for this example to work. In that file you can declare and export the Loader component like this...

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { LoaderComponent } from './loader.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, IonicModule],
    declarations: [LoaderComponent],
    exports: [LoaderComponent]
})
export class LoaderModule { }
```

Now that it is exported, it is available throughout the app. In order use it all you need to do is import the component module into the module that declares the page you want to use it in. Something like this...

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoaderModule } from '../loader/loader.module';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    LoaderModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

Hope his helps.